# Why is this code getting an assignment to 'char *' from 'char' error?

Tags: c, string, cs50

I am getting errors while compiling.

```
incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'string'
      (aka 'char *') from 'char'; take the address with &
```

**My Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>

int pallin(string A);
int main(void)
{
  printf("Enter the string to analyze\n");
  string S[10];
  S = GetString();
  int flag = pallin(S);
  if(flag == 0)
  {
    printf("Invalid input\n");
  }
  else if (flag == 1)
  {
    printf("Yes, the input is a pallindrome\n");
  }
  else{
    printf("The input is not a pallindrome\n");
  }
}

int pallin(string A)
{
  int flag;
  int n = strlen(A);
  if(n<=1)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else 
  {string B[10];int i = 0;

         while(A[i]!="\0")
         {
         B[i]=A[n-i-1];  //Getting error here.
         i++;
         }

      for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
      {
          if(B[j]!=A[j])
          {
              flag = 2;
          }
          else
          {
              flag = 1;
          }
      }
      return flag;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `char *S` instead of `char S[10]`. I can't find the `GetString()` function. In your code, `S` is an array. You cant assign a value to an array, can you?

Comment: @babon: the [tag:cs50] tag wiki has information about where the `<cs50.h>` header and characteristic functions such as `GetString()` and the (horrid) `string` typedef are given.

Comment: `GetString` returns a 'string' (`char *`).  You're assigning to `S` which is an array of 10 strings.  That is not a valid assignment.  `S[0]` would work.  Defining `string S = GetString();` would work too.  You have similar confusion in `pallin()` too.  Note that 'palindrome' has but one letter ell.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan Leffler. But Defining 'string S = Getstring( );' seems not of any use.

Comment: It probably isn't the only problem.  It is just one of probably many problems.  I've not compiled the code with a compiler; my mental compiler rejected that line.

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan Leffler, I got the bug. It was the declaration of the new string inside the pallin() function. I changed it to ' char B[10]; ' .

Comment: That and the use of `"\0"` in place of `'\0'`.  And 10 is very short.  You can check `amanaplanacanalpanama' or 'ablewasiereisawelba', etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not fond of the CS50 `typedef char *string;` — it doesn't help enough and does cause far too much confusion.  You can't declare arrays of characters using `string`.

This code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int palin(string A);

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter the string to analyze\n");
    string S = GetString();
    int flag = palin(S);
    if (flag == 0)
    {
        printf("Invalid input\n");
    }
    else if (flag == 1)
    {
        printf("Yes, the input is a palindrome\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The input is not a palindrome\n");
    }
}

int palin(string A)
{
    int flag;
    int n = strlen(A);
    if (n <= 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        char B[100];
        int i = 0;

        //while (A[i] != "\0")
        while (A[i] != '\0')
        {
            B[i] = A[n - i - 1]; // Getting error here.
            i++;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (B[j] != A[j])
            {
                flag = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

Changes are to `string S = GetString();` in `main()`; `char B[100];` in `palin()`; respelled 'palindrome'; use `'\0'` in place of `"\0"` (which has other problems too; it's the same as `""` in this context, and that isn't how you compare strings (in the generic sense as well as the CS50 sense) — you need `strcmp()` if you want to compare strings, but you don't in this context).

It doesn't free the allocated string.  It does produce the correct answers (program name `pa19`):

```
$ pa19
Enter the string to analyze
amanaplanacanalpanama
Yes, the input is a palindrome
$ pa19
Enter the string to analyze
abcde
The input is not a palindrome
$ pa19
Enter the string to analyze

Invalid input
$
```